# Apache Camel: switch routes based on value

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel, and trying to figure out the best way to configure switching routes based on certain values.

What I do at the moment is:

1. Retrieve the data from Kafka
2. Then, process it in a controller, and put a certain value in a header (here I feel something is not right)
3. Process the controller output header and check the value
4. Choose the route to go based on the header's value

```
this.from("direct:kafka.scenario.update").routeId("publish.scenario.kafka.controller.route")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Send Scenario update 2 Kafka Route").process(this.publishScenarioUpdateKafkaController).choice()
        .when( simple( "${out.header.updateType} == '" + ChangeType.UPDATE + "'" ))
        .process(this.publishVmsUpdateKafkaController)
        .to(dataRefScenarioUpdateProducerRoute)
        .when( simple( "${out.header.updateType} == '" + ChangeType.CREATE + "'" ))
        .process(this.publishVmsUpdateKafkaController)
        .to(dataRefScenarioCreateProducerRoute)
        .when( simple( "${out.header.updateType} == '" + ChangeType.DELETE + "'" ))
        .process(this.publishVmsUpdateKafkaController)
        .to(dataRefMessageDeleteProducerRoute);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a header value to route a message. See the answer below about content based router. If your message is json or xml then you could possibly do the routing without a processor.

Comment: Yeah Content Based Router can be okay to use. You can also use a java bean method with the recipient list pattern (or the optimised toD) where the returned value of the bean method is a Camel endpoint uri where to route to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are implementing [Content Based Router EIP](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) and I believe your approach is correct. You can always use `CamelTestSupport` to test your `RouteBuilders`.

Possible caveat: Please see if the `.when()` checks on `out.header.updateType` invokes `exchange.getOut()`(I don't remember it exactly), if it does, you may be losing vital information in `IN` message. This may cause unexpected results. Its just a word of caution and you may already know the difference. Ensure to reach and understand [this page](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html)  if you haven't done it already.